# Separate a list of input in string

Tags: java, string

I have this kind of input in string `david=michael,sarah,tina,justin`

David is the father and michael,sarah,tina and justin are his children. I want to make an array named michael and inside the array are his children. How can I do that in Java? Do I need to use StringTokenizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach, assuming that your input strings are always formatted the same way:

```
String input = "david=michael,sarah,tina,justin";
String father = input.split("=")[0];
String[] children = input.split("=")[1].split(",");
```

Note that if there's no `=` in your input you'll get an exception getting the children.

Comment: is this means i can get the name of the array is father's name?

Answer (score 0):

Use Properties to split the keys into reasonable groupings, then String.split() to pull out the children of the parent key.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] names = input.split("=|,");
```

names[0] is the parent, names[1] ... names[names.length - 1] are the kids.

Comment: means i have an array named names?

Comment: yes. You can't dynamically create variable names at runtime, as the JVM doesn't know what a local variable name is.